# How can I check if my string contains a period in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to be able to detect if a string has a . in it and return true/false based on that.

For example:

```
"myfile.doc" = TRUE
```

vs.

```
"mydirectory" = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `indexOf()`

```js
var str="myfile.doc";
var str2="mydirectory";

if(str.indexOf('.') !== -1)
{
  // would be true. Period found in file name
  console.log("Found . in str")
}

if(str2.indexOf('.') !== -1)
{
  // would be false. No period found in directory name. This won't run.
  console.log("Found . in str2")
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 when the character isn't found, not 0.

Comment: You should compare to -1 not 0; where the first character is a period, indexOf() would return 0.

Comment: Haha that's what happens when you're thinking of strpos() and coding indexOf()  :)

Answer (score 7):

Just test the return value of the `indexOf` method: `someString.indexOf('.') != -1`.  No need for a regex.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but here is a new way to do it (not supported in older browsers -> [can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-string-includes)):

```
str.includes('.'); //returns true or false
```

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Tested in Chrome - Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)) . Found Working !

Answer (score 1):

Some simple regex will do.

```
 if (myString.match(\.)) {
   doSomething();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what's already been said:

There are differing opinions on whether or not this is a good idea, but you can extend all `String` instances with a `contains` method if you like:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(char) {
    return this.indexOf(char) !== -1;
};
```

I tend to like this sort of thing, when it's (relatively) unambiguous what a method will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf. It returns an integer showing the position of a substring, or -1 if it isn't found.

For example:

```
var test="myfile.doc"
if (test.indexOf('.')) {alert("Period found!";}
else {alert("Period not found.  Sorry!";}
```

Comment: `if (test.indexOf('.'))` tests whether `indexOf` returns 0, not -1 as it should be testing, so your code will treat a string without a period as though it had one and a string beginning with a period as lacking one.